# Set textarea exact width, based on number of chars

Tags: javascript, html, css

Having the following problem.

I have to limit a users maximum number of chars, per line, on a textarea, but it seems cols does not do the trick, when including a vertical scrollbar:

```css
.textarea1 {
  resize: none;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
When no scrollbar is visible, it works fine using 50 chars.
<br />
<textarea class="textarea1" cols="50" rows="3">123456789!123456789!123456789!123456789!123456789!</textarea>

<br />
In this case, when the scrollbar is visible, at least 3 chars go to the next line.
<textarea class="textarea1" cols="50" rows="3">1234567890123456789!1234567890123456789!123456789!123456789!1234567890123456789!1234567890123456789!123456789!1234567890123456789!123456789!123456789!123456789!123456789!123456789!123456789!123456789!</textarea>


<br />
In this case, when I use 10 chars, I can fit an extra 1 char on each line.
<br />
<textarea class="textarea1" cols="10" rows="3">123456789!</textarea>


<br />
In this case, scrollbar visible, 1 char go to the next line.
<br />
<textarea class="textarea1" cols="10" rows="3">123456789!123456789!123456789!123456789!123456789!</textarea>
```

I considered calculating the width of the textarea, exemplified by this pseudo code.

`scrollbarWidth + textareaBorderWidth + (nChars * singleCharWidth)`

But no dice, it's too big with smaller lines (10 chars) and too small when using 50 chars.

Need support for IE10+, so ch units are a no go. Besides the support for ch on IE11 is doggy to say the least.

Any solutions?

Comment: Just a thought, but you could define the width of textarea to match cols by character units. 
.textarea1 {
  resize: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 10ch;
}

Comment: ah, forgot to mention, got to support IE10+, and ch units are not supported on IE10.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Tested it only on Chrome however.

```js
function scrollbarVisible(element) {
  return element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight;
}

$.each($("textarea"), function(index, value){
    var cols = value.getAttribute("cols");
    if (cols > 0){
        if (scrollbarVisible(value)){
            cols = parseInt(cols) + 3;
        }
        $(value).css("width", cols + "ch");
    }
})
```

```css
.textarea1 {
    resize: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1;
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
When no scrollbar is visible, it works fine using 50 chars.
<br />
<textarea class="textarea1" cols="50" rows="3">123456789!123456789!123456789!123456789!123456789!</textarea>
<br />
In this case, when the scrollbar is visible, at least 3 chars go to the next line.
<textarea class="textarea1" cols="50" rows="3">1234567890123456789!1234567890123456789!123456789!123456789!1234567890123456789!1234567890123456789!123456789!1234567890123456789!123456789!123456789!123456789!123456789!123456789!123456789!123456789!</textarea>
<br />
In this case, when I use 10 chars, I can fit an extra 1 char on each line.
<br />
<textarea class="textarea1" cols="10" rows="3">123456789!</textarea>
<br />
In this case, scrollbar visible, 1 char go to the next line.
<br />
<textarea class="textarea1" cols="10" rows="3">123456789!123456789!123456789!123456789!123456789!</textarea>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, that I need to support IE10+, so It won't work with ch units.